# Beginning a new session!

Tags: beginner, starter, sound-editing, mixing

I just finished recording a few sounds for a film that i am working on, for practice. I am working on nuendo 4. I wanted to know about the sample rate and the bit rate that i should use. 44/16 or 48/24? I also wanted to know what effect each of these have on the sound of the film and also, do i have to work on different sample rates and bit rates for films having different fps? I mean is the sample rate and bit rate different for a film that is 24 fps from a film that is 29fps?
P.S.: I am just a beginner, so please excuse me if i have used any wrong term. I hope i have put my question forward properly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The industry standard right now is 24bit, 48kHz. The frame rate doesn't influence those settings. Depending on the type of work you are doing (dialog editing, foley editing, sound effects editing or design), your sample rate may vary anywhere from 48k all the way up to 192k. But 99% of the sessions that are ultimately destined for a professional dub stage will be saved as 24/48.

Answer (score 3):

24 bit 48 kHz, if you are pitch shifting use 96 kHz.

Answer (score 1):

44.1 kHz sample rate should be fine but if you would like to do something like pitch shifting or time warp 96 kHz is strongly recommended. Your audio waves will have more detail in time. Same practice is applicable in bit depth. 24 bit is basic level. In Nuendo you should use 32 bit.

I **strongly suggest to open manual** :] Steinberg explain theory very well in manual.

There is many interesting articles on this forum about high sample rates

You always can do mix down of your project with dithering for right bit depth (in nuendo just add master diner effect on last insert slot on your master channel)...